# Sending data retrieved from webhook to frontend via websocket

Tags: go, websocket, webhooks

I have a **mobile** application which requires **live** **data** from an external service. Currently, I'm building a **Golang** backend application which **retrieves** the data from the external service via **webhook**.

Is it possible to send that data to my mobile application through **websocket** after receiving it from the **webhook**?

I did some research online and there isn't much resource on this topic.

I saw some repo's like https://github.com/fabianlindfors/sockethook but this was quite old already.

Is there like some **extra stuff** that is happening to convert the data from the **webhook** to **websocket** or is it just a straight forward thing where i get the data from **webhook**, process it then send it through **websocket**? Or is there a better way in approaching this? I'm also using **fiber** for the backend part.